# Html5 videos from Youtube aren't loading in Google Chrome

Tags: 11.10, google-chrome, youtube, html5

When I go on to Youtube and join the html5 trial the videos no longer load. They show the 'loading' circle and stay black. When I use flash instead on Linux the videos load. When I use Google Chrome on Windows 7 with html5 there's no problem.

Comment: You can test general HTML 5 Video Support for you browser at http://video.eustasy.co.uk/ I'd suggest clicking the top video unless you have a fairly large screen. Note: My HTML5 Video Works Fine (Chrome 14, Ubuntu 11.10).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the videos from the site load fine. I just tried with youtube again, now it works. I have no idea why it works now, it didn't work for several days, that's why I posted the question.